# Android: Findout list of devices connected to network

Tags: android

I want to make application which gives me the list of all the devices that are connected to my current network connection.

For eg. When i press on search button in bluetooth application gives me the list of bluetooth device that are in range , Similarly i need to develop application in when when i click on search button then it should able to give the list of all the devices that are connected to my network.
I am familiar with the Networkmanager and the NetworkInfo Api.

If u have any idea how can i do this,please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you implement this?
If yes then plz give me how you did that?

Answer (score 11):

If you mean you want to see all the devices connected to your current WiFi connection (and you are not trying to do Ad Hoc networking), then you are essentially wanting to run a network scanner.

There are a bunch of these around. This one has the source available on github

http://rorist.github.com/android-network-discovery/

Comment: mention URL is a good approach but I just check app, it is not able to track the whole network. E.g if network have  device in 199.199.50.<0-255> and 199.199.51.<0-200> but if your mobile ip is 199.199.50.156 then app will get only 199.199.50.<0-255> on able to track 199.199.51.<0-255>. not able to work like  Fing app

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now to get the network devices using NSD Android new feature and for this required minimum version 16 level Jellybean

Here is the link for NSD

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: how to use it, it's not clear in the link , you've provide

Comment: I used Network Service Discovery in Android, but unfortunately I am unable to get the list of all devices connected to the network.

Comment: Agree with sadeepmaarm's comment. I tried with its demo app (nsdChat) I just got 5-6 devices. Actually, there are 250+ devices