# How to detect all the Devices connected in a WiFi network from Android App

Tags: java, android, networking, hardware, monitoring

I am developing an app in which I need to scans WiFi network and display the list of all connected devices.

Allow a use to tap on a device and the app should show all the hardware info of that particular device. Here by hardware I mean - RAM, Storage Media, Storage Capacity, Device Name, Device IP address, etc.

Now this device can be anything like xbox, a laptop with Linux/Windows, mobile phone like iPhone or any Andorid based smart phone or even a printer.

How can I scans WiFi network and query/detect all the devices attached to it?

What are the protocols that I need to use to get list of hardware in a particular device irrespective of the OS running on it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3708345/1321873

Comment: If you are lucky enough to get an answer, it might worth trying to contact this team: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en

Comment: I have know of another software with more features than Fing! Check it out: http://bit.ly/QICmG2. I want to achieve something similar to this but it should work with any kind of device that can connect to WiFi.

Comment: Not all the features of fing, but faster and doesn't crash https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wwnd.netmapper

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the [Network Discovery](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/) github project could help you. It lists all users connected to WiFi with IP and MAC addresses and gathers even some information like open ports, device name, ping, etc.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

Check [requestPeers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#requestPeers(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener)) of 
 [WifiP2pManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html)

As per documents it seeks
[PeerListListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener.html) which returns [WifiP2pDeviceList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDeviceList.html) carrying list of [WifiP2pDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDevice.html) which carries deviceAddress, deviceName, primaryDeviceType, secondaryDeviceType, status and other attributes.

Comment: hi javanator, i tried with WifP2pManager, but not able to detect any devices through requestPeers(). This approach is for wifi Direct. can you help me for finding a Local device (LAN) connected to the wifi router.

Comment: @Vrajesh you need first to run discoverPeers() and then on completion run requestPeers()

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

> "Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point (Android's Wi-Fi P2P framework complies with the Wi-Fi Alliance's Wi-Fi Direct™ certification program). Using these APIs, you can discover and connect to other devices when each device supports Wi-Fi P2P, then communicate over a speedy connection across distances much longer than a Bluetooth connection. This is useful for applications that share data among users, such as a multiplayer game or a photo sharing application."
>   Blockquote