# How to detect all the printers in a WiFi network from Java or Win form App?

Tags: java, windows, winforms, protocols

I am developing an app in which I need to scans LAN/WiFi network and display the list of all connected/not connected printers.

Allow a use to tap on a printer and the app should show all the hardware info of that particular printer. 
Here by hardware I mean - DeviceName, Serial, Device IP Address, etc.

How can I scans LAN/WiFi network and query/detect all the printers attached to it?

What are the protocols that I need to use to get list of hardware in a particular device irrespective of the OS running on it?

Comment: you can check answer at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386948/how-to-detect-all-the-devices-connected-in-a-wifi-network-from-android-app

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, I am developing an app in Windows not for Android. Do you have solutions for this case?