# how to write android program to detect all the Devices connected in a WiFi network?

Tags: java, android

How to write an android program to detect all the devices connected in a WiFi network??

I am a beginner in android.  I am trying to write a android program to detect all the devices connected in a WiFi network.

Comment: This is an advanced topic for beginning android programming.

Comment: This question might be relevant: [How to detect all the Devices connected in a WiFi network from Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386948/how-to-detect-all-the-devices-connected-in-a-wifi-network-from-android-app)

Comment: Begin with the available resources on building an app. From there you can proceed to ask specific questions about working with the WiFi interfaces and locating other devices. All apps begin the same with with a manifest and an activity and so on, so start there.  https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: bro try (Network Discovery github )  :D   https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/