# How to detect host names in LAN

Tags: android, lan, pinging

I want to detect connected device to my wifi and their information such as device name, mac address, manufacturer.
I can get connected devices IP using pinging but how can I get the device name and mac address of those?

Edit:
I want to do that in my android phone.

Comment: log in to Your router for mac, device name

Comment: @Vairis I want do that in android

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386948/how-to-detect-all-the-devices-connected-in-a-wifi-network-from-android-app